# What percent of Attack Speed would max Evelyn with her ult on?

Tags: league-of-legends

Trying to create an AD carry build but cant figure out the best items due to not knowing the exact %AS to use as to not waste it with her ultimate being on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Her base attack speed is 0.658 +3.84% per level. At level 18 her attack speed is 1.087. Her ulti gives her  75% attack speed increase(of her base attack speed.) That puts her at 1.90225.  Attack speed caps at 2.5 so we need to increase the attack speed approximately .6

An additional 55% attack speed from items will allow it to cap.